# .htaccess redirect preserve square braces in target url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

aam a bit stuck / confused.
I want to change the query string on a url like

from

```
https://www.example.com/sub1/sub1-1/sub1-1-1/title.html?ref=123
```

to the same url but change the query parameters to e.g. something[else]=321

```
https://www.example.com/sub1/sub1-1/sub1-1-1/title.html?something[else]=321
```

ok

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^ref=123
RewriteRule sub1/sub1-1/sub1-1-1/title.html$ /sub1/sub1-1/sub1-1-1/title.html?something[else]=321 [L,R=301]
```

it works but the square brackets are always rewritten to %5b and %5d and result in an url like

```
https://www.example.com/sub1/sub1-1/sub1-1-1/title.html?something%5belse%5d=321
```

how can I keep the square brackets?
tried to escape them in the htaccess

```
RewriteRule sub1/sub1-1/sub1-1-1/title.html$ /sub1/sub1-1/sub1-1-1/title.html?something\[else\]=321 [L,R=301]
```

but it doesn't work

thx for your input

Comment: The address line can not represent square brackets, these brackets are converted as html / url entity
This is the right way: https://www.example.com/sub1/sub1-1/sub1-1-1/title.html?something%5belse%5d=321
-> 
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: sorry might be my poor english.
the system I am using is typo3, and there are many extensions, that generate urls with square braces like    ....?tx_extension_pi1[var]=whatever and when I paste the url like https://www.example.com/sub1/sub1-1/sub1-1-1/title.html?something[else]=321 in my safari it works properly as well and the urls shows the brackets and not %5B/D

Comment: if you use typo3, why you doesn't use the default .htaccess and change the default condition? TYPO3 can that per default :) if your server have mod_rewrite activated

Comment: ok the case is the following.
I want to track the referrer of a page with a powermail plugin, so I get the referrer by default in the receiver mail. ndfortunately the mail sent to several online portals is in the form ?ref=XYZ but powermail for GP vars looks for ?tx_powermail_pi1[ref]=XYZ so I thought good to know for the future, but now that the urls are sent to the magazines with ?ref=XYZ i might redigect them this time. result it, works, but the url does not look nice, so atm just a cosmetic problem,

Comment: if you add your own get params to the installtool settings: cHashExcludedParameters for caching problems :) the chash list will be not so increase :) Sry that i cant help :)

Comment: cheers episch ...

anybody else perhaps a hint how to force the htacess to render the %5B %5D for square braces in the target url, so that it shows nicely in the browser url?

thx and rgds, stooky